# What is the relationship between exponentials and complex coordinates?

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

I find it hard to grasp my head around the fact that $$ e^{ai} $$ gives a rotation around the unit circle. I'm aware that $$ e^{ai} = \cos(a) + i\sin(a) $$ but I can not for the life of me give this equation meaning.

What is the relationship between Eulers number and circles?

Comment: You may also find this [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_0yfvm0UoU&t=9s) video helpful. Or its [later revision](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvmuCPvRoWQ), though that one may bring in some harder concepts.